# while(reader.read()) counter

Tags: c#

If I'm using while(reader.read()...) is there an internal index available of do need to create my own int counter++ deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own index variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `reader` is an [`IDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) then, no, there is no internal index available.